# In Haskell, can you have a signature of a function that calls other functions but doesn't have an implementation?

Tags: function, haskell, syntax, tree, function-signature

So I'm learning Haskell and I have to implement a treeunzip function that takes a tree of the type (Tree (a,b)) where 'a' and 'b' are integers and returns a list of the two trees unzipped, that is (Tree a, Tree b).

I can get one of the two trees but I can't put them together in a list. What I came up with is this:

```
treeunzip :: (NewTree) -> (treeunzipL, treeunzipR)
```

NewTree is defined as:

```
data NewTree = NewLeaf | NewNode Int Int NewTree NewTree deriving Show
```

Tree is defined as:

```
data Tree = Leaf | Node Int Tree Tree deriving Show
```

Here are the treeunzipL and treeunzipR functions, I don't know if it matters.

```
treeunzipL :: (NewTree) -> (Tree)
treeunzipL NewLeaf = (Leaf)
treeunzipL (NewNode x y lSubTree rSubTree) = (Node x (treeunzipL (lSubTree)) (treeunzipL (rSubTree)))


treeunzipR :: (NewTree) -> (Tree)
treeunzipR NewLeaf = (Leaf)
treeunzipR (NewNode x y lSubTree rSubTree) = (Node y (treeunzipR (lSubTree)) (treeunzipR (rSubTree)))
```

Now that obviously gives me an error when loading the module because treeunzip has a signature but not an implementation. Is there any way to get around this?

Thank you.

Comment: `treeunzipped :: NewTree -> (Tree, Tree)`.  The type doesn't care about function names used to implement the function.

Comment: Also, you don't need two separate types if you parameterize the original type. `data Tree a = Leaf | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)`, then `treeunzipped :: Tree (a,b) -> (Tree a, Tree b)`.

Comment: Ok I think I'm going to study some more theory because all I understood from your comments was that a function only contains data types and not function calls. Not sure what parameterizing means.

Thank you though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you are trying to imply the definition in the type. The two are separate and must be provided separately. (The compiler can infer a type from a definition, but it cannot infer the definition from the type.)

```
treeunzip :: NewTree -> (Tree, Tree)
treeunzip t = (treeunzipL t, treeunzipR t)
```

However, you should parameterize your original type to

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

so that you only need one `treeunzip` function:

```
treeunzip :: Tree (a, b) -> (Tree a, Tree b)
treeunzip Leaf = (Leaf, Leaf)
treeunzip (Node (a, b) left right) = ((Node a left' right'),
                                      (Node b left'' right''))
    where (left', left'') = treeunzip left
          (right', right'')  treeunzip right

> treeunzip (Node (1,2) (Node (3,4) Leaf Leaf) (Node (5,6) Leaf Leaf))
(Node 1 (Node 3 Leaf Leaf) (Node 5 Leaf Leaf),Node 2 (Node 4 Leaf Leaf) (Node 6 Leaf Leaf))
```

Comment: Ok adding the line:

    treeunzip t = (treeunzipL t, treeunzipR t)

Made it work. That was the trick I was looking for.